# Taking several fields from multiple XML files that are in a desktop folder and placing them into an Access Table

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access

This is my fourth time writing this so bear with me. I am trying to solve this problem all day and I feel like I am really close to a solution but just not quite there. I have read a bunch of articles on Stack Overflow and elsewhere but cannot figure it out. Part of this code was borrowed from another solution on SO and the other part that is not is working properly (as far as I can tell)

What I am trying to do is allow a user to click a button in a form in MS Access which would run the VBA code I have below.

1. The first part of the code will open a dialog box that allows the user to select a folder. This folder will house all of the XML files which are to be updated into the Table. (This will be an ongoing process)
2. From this point I would like to create a loop which will cycle through each XML file and grab 5 data points (labeled *serial, CalDueDate, date, time,* and *OverallResult*) then put those 5 fields into an Access table.

I have ran the solution and debugger over and over and I keep coming up with different errors. However, I believe I have narrowed it down to one last error (fingers crossed) and that is what I am asking the community for help with.

```vb
Private Sub Command4_Click()
'Folder selector'
Dim xStrPath As String
Dim xFileDialog As Object
Dim xFile As String
Dim xCount As Long
'Now merge XML lookup and table entry'
Const cintNumTables As Integer = 1
Dim intInnerLoop As Integer
Dim intOuterLoop As Integer
Dim objDoc As Object
Dim objNode As Object
Dim strFieldList As String
Dim strMsg As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strTable As String
Dim strTag As String
Dim strTagList As String
Dim strUID As String
Dim strValueList As String
Dim varTags As Variant

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With xFileDialog
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select a Folder to Import XML Files from"
        .Show
End With

xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xml")
xCount = 1
  Do While xFile <> ""
    For intOuterLoop = 1 To cintNumTables
        Select Case intOuterLoop
        Case 1
            strTable = "XMLConvertedTable"
            strTagList = "serial,CalDueDate,date,time,overallResult"
            strFieldList = "Serial, DateCalibrationDue, DateCalibrated, TimeCalibrated, TestResult"
        Case Else
            'oops!'
            strTable = vbNullString
        End Select
        If Len(strTable) > 0 Then
            varTags = Split(strTagList, ",")
            strValueList = "'" & strUID & "'"
            For intInnerLoop = 0 To UBound(varTags)
                strTag = varTags(intInnerLoop)
                strValueList = strValueList & ", '" & "'"
            Next intInnerLoop
'works? to this point'
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO " & strTable & " (" & strFieldList & ")" & vbNewLine & "Values (" & strValueList & ");"
            Debug.Print strSQL
            CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
        End If
    Next intOuterLoop
  Loop
ExitHere:
    Set objNode = Nothing
    Set objDoc = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    strMsg = "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description _
        & ") in procedure Try Again"
    MsgBox strMsg
    GoTo ExitHere
End Sub
```

SAMPLE XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resultset>
     <info>
           <instrument>instrument 1</instrument>
           <serial>000000</serial>
           <calDueDate>12 June 2019</calDueDate>
           <date>May 13 2019</date>
           <time>4:48:00 PM</time>
           <overallResult>PASS</overallResult>
           <opID>Not Used</opID>
```

---

UPDATE

I have edited the code to look like the following in order to ease the confusion of tracing everything. I have also found that the error lies somewhere in the SQL statement. I have found that the variables strTable, strTagList, and strFieldList are carrying through the code correctly through to the SQL statement.

```vb
Private Sub Command5_Click()

'Folder selector'
 Dim xStrPath As String
 Dim xFileDialog As Object
 Dim xFile As String
 Dim xCount As Long
 'Now merge XML lookup and table entry'
 Const cintNumTables As Integer = 2
 Dim intInnerLoop As Integer
 Dim intOuterLoop As Integer
 Dim objDoc As Object
 Dim objNode As Object
 Dim strFieldList As String
 Dim strMsg As String
 Dim strSQL As String
 Dim strTable As String
 Dim strTag As String
 Dim strTagList As String
 Dim strUID As String
 Dim strValueList As String
 Dim varTags As Variant

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With xFileDialog
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Select a Folder to Import XML Files from"
    .Show
End With

xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xml")
    Do While xFile <> ""
        strTable = "XMLConvertedTable"
        strTagList = "serial, CalDueDate, date, time, overallResult"
        strFieldList = "Serial, DateCalibrationDue, DateCalibrated,     
        TimeCalibrated, TestResult"
        If Len(strTable) > 0 Then
            varTags = Split(strTagList, ",")
'There is an error in the next statement (error 13)'
            strValueList = varTags & ",'"
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO " & strTable & " (" & _
            strFieldList & ")" & "VALUES (" & strValueList & ");"
            Debug.Print strSQL
        CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
    End If
 Loop

ExitHere:
Set objNode = Nothing
Set objDoc = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
strMsg = "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description _
    & ") in procedure Try Again"
MsgBox strMsg
GoTo ExitHere
End Sub
```

The error I am getting now is

> Error 13 (Type Mismatch) in procedure Try Again

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Image of Access Table Design View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAYs3.png)

Comment: I attempted to address your original issue. Now the original question has been edited, and you're asking a completely different question. This is not done in SO. Please limit questions to one specific issue, and open a new question if you have follow-on issues.

Comment: Your new question has been asked and answered several times. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22788173/data-type-mismatch-on-sql-query-in-vba), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52638598/data-type-mismatch-in-criteria-expression-in-vba-access-sql) are a few examples.

Comment: I was only trying to simplify, I ultimately would like the original code to work and I was also showing updates to what I was coming up with. I apologize for this inconvenience, I didn't think it was a separate question as I am trying to get the same result.

Comment: @SmrtGrunt your links did not fix the problem. Should I create a new post with the <updated code> I provided? The problem I believe lies in the <<<strValueList = varTags & ",'"
>>> line of code

Comment: No where are you actually parsing XML data with DOM/XPath methods. Also, sample XML is cut off. Does your nodes repeat? This is very important to know.

Answer (score 0):

In your `varTags` loop, this line:
`strValueList = strValueList & ", '" & "'"`
appears to be missing a reference to `strTag`.

This will cause the mismatch in argument numbers, as the size of `strFieldList` and `strValueList` won't be the same.

I'm guessing it should be `strValueList = strValueList & ", '" & strTag & "'"`.

Also, you probably shouldn't have the `vbNewLine` in the `strSQL` string.

Comment: I am still getting the same error "Error 3346 (Number of query values and destination fields are not the same) in procedure try again.

```strValueList = strValueList & ", '" & strTag & "'"

            Next intInnerLoop

'works? to this point

strSQL = "INSERT INTO " & strTable & " (" & strFieldList & ")" & "Values (" & strValueList & ");"

Debug.Print strSQL```

Comment: @Nichowags Does the number of fields in your query match the number of fields in the destination database, or is it too large?

Comment: Also, check your spaces in the SQL query

Comment: Please see revised code and the Access table design view image I submitted. I feel like it has to be something pretty simple that I am doing wrong I just can't see it.

Comment: I have solved this there were several issues and I do not have a copy of code on mobile, but I believe to get the desired results I scrapped this code all together.